# cellForRowAtIndexPath for 2 tableview in a storyboard, unrecognized selector sent to instance error

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

This is my code and my error. I have 2 `tableview`s in a storyboard with 2 `customcell`s. But I can't set `cellforrowatindexpath` method for `table2`:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if(tableView.tag==1){
    static NSString *CellIndentifier = @"CustomCell";
    CustomCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIndentifier];
    if (cell==nil) {
        cell=[[CustomCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIndentifier];

    }
    cell.text1Label.text=[moviesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.text2Label.text=[moviesArraytext2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        return cell;
    }
    else if (tableView.tag==2){
        static NSString *CellIndentifier2 = @"CategoryCell";
        CategoryCell *cell2=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIndentifier2];
        if (cell2==nil) {
            cell2=[[CategoryCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIndentifier2];

        }
        cell2.categoryLabel.text=[hotProgramByCatArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        return cell2;
return nil;
```

and this is the error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewCell categoryLabel]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8e7f560'
```

Comment: Looks like the problem is with how you're creating your custom cell, not the fact that you have 2 table views.

Comment: Have you set up cell Indentifier in IB?

Comment: I think the problem is with return value.Return nil is that true?

Comment: yes i have set up indentifier for cell, tags for tableview

Comment: Did you change the class of the cell in IB to CategoryCell? The error is saying that you're trying to access the property, categoryLabel, in a UITableViewCell (not your CategoryCell).

Comment: Did you do enough Google searching to know what "unrecognized selector" means???

Comment: Take a look at this link it may solve your problem

   http://stackoverflow.com/a/27292651/3282447

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the outlets for the views on the custom cells are wired up to the cell itself and not the "File's Owner".

You can check this by looking at the Connections Inspector in Interface Builder.