# [UITableViewCell nameLabel]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I was wondering whether anyone knew how to solve this problem?

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewCell nameLabel]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa9ca4936c0'

My code is:

```
(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)foldertableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *foldersIdentifier = @"FolderCell";

    FolderCellTableViewCell *cell = (FolderCellTableViewCell *) [foldertableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:foldersIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FolderCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    cell.nameLabel.text = [folders objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.thumbnailImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[thumbnails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    cell.datesLabel.text = [dates objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

It worked fine at first but when I tried to connect a table view to a collection view this problem started to show up and it crashes. No idea whether it is detailed enough, though. I'm new to the programming world, thus if more detail is needed please let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "connect a table view to a collection view"?! One cannot "connect" them... Please clarify

Comment: @Julian raise a valid question but it looks problem is in your folders Array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems like you aren't using your subclass of the table cell. The error shows you try to use regular UITableCell instances. Make sure you set the cell class in the nib or storyboard as FolderCellTableViewCell,Please follow steps below,It may help you

1. select your cell view,
2. open the inspector and goto to tab 3.
3. Fill out 'Custom Class' to point to YOUR class FolderCellTableViewCell

Answer (score 1):

You're casting the cell you get to a `FolderCellTableViewCell` but in fact the cell you receive from `[foldertableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:foldersIdentifier];` is a `UITableViewCell` not a `FolderCellTableViewCell`. Make sure your storyboard table view cell is of class `FolderCellTableViewCell`.